# How do I set React (create-react-app) to display image

Tags: reactjs, image, url, proxy, cra

I have create-react-app application and I am unable to display the image.
In a code I have

`<img src="/files/2k28WHrMCJu9jSEEss0Y9sKV7Oqf4b/0/120" alt="" />`

use .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/files.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

it should transfer to

`<img src="/files/files.php?url=2k28WHrMCJu9jSEEss0Y9sKV7Oqf4b/0/120" alt="" />`

folder structure app is:

```
|- build
|- files
|    |- files.php 
|- public
|    |- .htaccess
|    |- api
|    |- ...
|- src
|    |- folders with all pages, components, ...
|- storage
|    |- all images
```

PHP code (files.php) returns

```
header('Last-Modified: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) .' GMT');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header('Expires:'. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expiry) .' GMT');
header('ETag: '. $etag);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

If I run the application in build mode (from the build directory), everything works perfectly.
It doesn't work in a development environment.
What is the reason that it works in build mode and not in development mode.
Is the reason a directory structure or a proxy or something else?

The question is why it works in the build app and development does not.
If I use the direct URL to open the photo to the browser
`http://buil-app/files/2k28WHrMCJu9jSEEss0Y9sKV7Oqf4b/0/120`
in the build app, the photo will be displayed.
Using development mode
`http://localhost:3000/files/2k28WHrMCJu9jSEEb7/O/120` show not photo but applications. Rewrite didn't work in .htaccess or didn't find a path?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your react app put the images under `public/static/images` and address them like this:

```
<img src="/static/test.jpg" alt="test" />
```